# Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, linode

My website in production is currently down and I am not sure what's going on.

here is my nginx conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.joinery.nyc joinery.nyc;
  root /data/joinery.nyc/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;

  return 301 https://joinery.nyc$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name www.joinery.nyc joinery.nyc;

  ssl    on;

  ssl_certificate    /opt/nginx/conf/joinery.nyc.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key    /opt/nginx/conf/joinery.nyc.key;


  location /attachments {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
     proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/attachments;
     proxy_cache images;
     proxy_cache_valid 200 30d;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_x_proxy_uncache;
   }  
   location / {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81/;
   }
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name joinery.nyc;

    root /data/joinery.nyc/current/public;

      passenger_enabled on;
      rack_env production;
      passenger_min_instances 2;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
      # to serve pre-gzipped version, requires nginx compiled with this
      gzip_static on;

      # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
      # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
      # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
    }
}
```

When I check the error log under `/opt/nginx/logs/error.log` I get these messages:

```
2018/01/05 11:47:48 [alert] 10909#0: *3 write() to "/opt/nginx/logs/access.log" failed (28: No space left on device) while logging request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: joinery.nyc, request: "GET /import/facebook/a?referral=AV4 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "passenger:/tmp/passenger.1.0.10889/generation-0/request", host: "joinery.nyc", referrer: "http://m.facebook.com"

[ 2018-01-05 11:47:57.6775 10893/7fcc59c71700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is cdbb37a0. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.

App 11191 stderr: id: write error
App 11191 stderr: : No space left on device
App 11191 stdout: 
App 11191 stderr: log writing failed. No space left on device @ io_write - /data/nestie.co/releases/20180104181346/log/newrelic_agent.log
App 11191 stderr:
```

FYI: this all started after i tried adding a CDN to my application (Cloudfront). I modified my nginx web server to enable cross-origin requests, but then reverted back the changes as I thought that was the issue with my site being down. However still down and no idea

EDIT:

running `$ df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda        40895824 40470392         0 100% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
devtmpfs         4078284        4   4078280   1% /dev
none              816224      316    815908   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             4081120        0   4081120   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
overflow            1024      740       284  73% /tmp
```

Comment: Can you check your space left on the server? Since the error is clearly stating that, maybe it crashes because no space left to write

Comment: @Niklas here is the update above. I also just upgraded my storage space on the server but still getting an error about storage space.